# How to propagateComposedEvents to Button from upper MouseArea?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Demo:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow{
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "button"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Button onClicked")
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: {
            console.log("MouseArea onClicked")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
    }
}
```

I expected below when click the button

```
qml: MouseArea onClicked
qml: Button onClicked
```

but only got

```
qml: MouseArea onClicked
```

How to make the event pass to Button? and why the current demo cannot do that?

Answer (score 0):

it seems a temp solution is:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow{
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "button"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Button onClicked")
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("MouseArea onClicked")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
        onPressed: {
            console.log("MouseArea onPressed")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
qml: MouseArea onPressed
qml: Button onClicked
```

it is not what I want but can solve my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a specific case which you are trying, one solution which you can do is to call the button clicked signal from onClicked in mouse area

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow{
width: 500
height: 500
visible: true

Button {
    id:btn
    text: "button"
    onClicked: {
        console.log("Button onClicked")
    }

}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: {
        console.log("MouseArea onClicked")
        btn.clicked()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why the current demo cannot do that?

The point is that the order of the components in the file matters, and this order affects how they overlap each other. For example, in [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-topic.html#manual-positioning) case of manual positioning, we see how one component overlaps another, what is reflected in their display relative to each other. *One component will overlap another component if it is located below in the code*.

So in your case, it is not surprising that you get the following output:

```
qml: MouseArea onClicked
```

since the `MouseArea` is located after the `Button`, and mouse events do not reach the `Button`. If you arrange them in the reverse order (first the area, and then the button), then the output will be as follows:

```
qml: Button onClicked
```

### How to make the event pass to Button?

If a click occurs, then it must refer to some one specific component. This means that it will not be possible to click on one component, but to process this click already in several. Therefore, in your case, you can first click on the `MouseArea`, and then provoke a click from the code on the `Button`, or vice versa.

Thus, if you want to get exactly the output that you indicated in the question, the already proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67681560/14997895) will suit you. However, in this case, we lose the ability to use the standard functionality of the `Button` component, such as "change color when pressed", and more. So I can suggest this solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: {
            console.log("MouseArea onClicked")
        }

        Button {
            text: "button"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Button onClicked")
                ma.clicked(ma.mouseX, ma.mouseY)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
qml: Button onClicked
qml: MouseArea onPressed
```

However, in this case, pressing will work in two places, and at the same time the above-described functionality of the `Button` is preserved. You can also place the `Button` under the `MouseArea` - this will work too.

Comment: Hi, I think MouseButton passes the mouse event to the Button even in the different element order or z order. you can try the example code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67631411/3308570. my current implementation is completed cannot specific the explicit id. I am looking for a way like `propagateEvents` rather than `propagateComposedEvents`.

Comment: Hi, in [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67631411/3308570) solution, the components have the same stacking order (also known as [z](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop)). By default it is 0, however, if you change it for the `Button`, for example, to 1, then you can make sure that mouse events will not pass to `MouseArea`.

As for my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702865/14997895), instead of id, you can use the [parent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#parent-prop) property, or if you have a deep hierarchy you can use the signal and slot system.