# MouseArea does not pass click to CheckBox

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Take a look at this QML snipped:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Rectangle {
    
    color: "blue"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    
    CheckBox {
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
        }    
    }
}
```

I want to add `MouseArea` over `CheckBox` so I can handle doubleclick. However no matter how and what I do `CheckBox` stops working (clicking it won't show checked mark) as soon as there is `MouseArea` over it.

What's wrong here?

Comment: _it will not be possible to click on one component, but to process this click already in several_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702865/5366641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically toggle Qt Quick 2 `CheckBox` with [AbstractButton.toggle()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#toggle-method). Also, `MouseArea` `propagateComposedEvents` property works only with other MouseAreas and not with *Qt Quick Controls QML types*.

I don't know your use case so I add few possibilities below.

**Signal connect() method**

Easiest way to achieve toggling through MouseArea is to create *signal chain* by connecting MouseArea clicked to CheckBox clicked.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "blue"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
        onClicked: toggle()
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        Component.onCompleted: mouseArea.clicked.connect(clicked)
    }
}
```

Note that double click always starts with a single click. If you want to **catch double clicks with MouseArea** you can e.g. use a Timer for preventing propagating clicks to CheckBox.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "blue"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (timer.running) {
                    return
                }
                checkBox.toggle()
                timer.start()
            }
            Timer {
                id: timer
                interval: 250
                repeat: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to support CheckBox's pressed visualization and/or if you want to use bigger MouseArea than the size of the CheckBox you can take a look into this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306758/cant-click-button-below-a-mousearea/69319941#69319941)** of the question *Can't click button below a MouseArea*.